# Customer Report showing blank

Tags: cartthrob

I'm seeing a strange behavior in the Customer Reports screen where none of the customer names are showing. We're seeing the customer totals and also the ability to export to CSV, and even more interesting, the pagination; none of the customers are listed in the table though. The rest of the CT reports are all working properly, but this specific report is showing blank.

Using EE 2.9.2 and CT 2.61

Comment: I'm also seeing this suddenly. Did you ever find and answer?

Comment: No, it's still showing mostly blank. Though I am seeing two customers out of 303 in the report and haven't had the time to see why those two are showing but nothing else is; it may be able to give us a clue. 

No response from CT is unfortunate. A current client did his own research on eCommerce plugins for his website and he specifically asked us to use Expresso Store instead of CT because of the support.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is that the report only shows entries with an open status. Are the few entries you're seeing set to open?  Are the rest set to some other status?